# Definition of 'saturated' set?

Tags: general-topology

My notes from the lecture says "Let $X$ be a topological space and let $R$ be an equivalence relation. Then, $A \subseteq X$ is called saturated with respect to $R$ if it is a union of equivalence classes."
This statement doesn't make sense to me. I have learnt about quotient spaces $X/R$ which is a set of all equivalence classes. So, since $A$ is a subset of $X$, how can it be a union of equivalence classes? I would understand the statement if it said $A$ is a subset of $X/R$?

Thanks.

Comment: An equivalence class of a relation on a set `X` is a subset of `X`. Equivalence classes form a partition of the set `X`.

Comment: Don't you mean $A\subseteq X$ instead of $A\in X$?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since equivalence classes are subsets of $X$, a *union of equivalence classes* is a subset of $X$. A subset of $X/R$ would be a *set of equivalence classes*.

Every saturated set $A$ is of the form $q^{-1}(q(A))$ where $q$ is the quotient map $X\to X/R, x\mapsto [x]$. More generally, if $q:X\to Y$ is any function, one may call a set $A\subseteq X$ *q-saturated* when it is of the form $q^{-1}(B)$ for some $B\subseteq Y$. But this is equivalent to saturated sets for equivalence relation since the fibers $q^{-1}(y)$ can be thought of as equivalence classes. A preimage is then saturated with respect to that relation.