# Equivalence Relation saturating a subset

Tags: equivalence-relations

Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173523/definition-of-saturated-set), can someone help me understand (even better with some basic visualization) the meaning of "saturation" when it comes to [partition](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/347.summer14/relations.pdf) and its counterpart (equivalence relation)? Does saturation mean that there is a union of equivalence classes that make up the entire set `S` or just part of it?

Comment: The linked Question seems to define "saturated subset" in a clear way.  Perhaps you should take the initiative to give an example to illustrate what is unclear.  It means that "there is a union of equivalence classes that make up [exactly] the entire" subset $S$ of the possibly larger set $X$ for which a partition (equiv. an equivalence relation) is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set and let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Then, $X$ can be partitioned into pairwise disjoint equivalence classes $\{E_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ where $I$ is some index set. Now, every $E_\alpha$ is by definition a subset of $X$. So, in symbolic terms, we have
$$
X = \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} E_\alpha
$$
and $E_\alpha \cap E_\beta = \varnothing$ whenever $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Consider an arbitrary (for now) subset $A$ of $X$. Because $A \subseteq X$, it is clear that
$$
A \subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} E_\alpha.
$$
However, $A$ might not be the union of equivalence classes, i.e. it may be impossible to write
$$
A = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J} E_\alpha
$$
for any subset $J$ of $I$. This is because an equivalence class $E_\alpha$ containing a point $a \in A$ **may also** contain points from $X \setminus A$.

Next let us assume that $A$ is saturated. The definition of saturation prevents the above from occurring. Namely, it states that $A$ can be expressed **exactly** as the union of *some* of these equivalence classes. Put otherwise, the saturation of $A$ ensures that for each $\alpha \in I$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:star}\tag{$\star$}
A \cap E_\alpha \neq \varnothing \implies E_\alpha \subseteq A.
\end{equation}
Therefore, if $A$ is saturated, then an equivalence class of $X$ either contains *only* points from $A$, or none at all.

Comment: So, `A` can be any arbitrary set that we can call "saturated" as long as it holds the principle that it is composed of one or more equivalence classes of `X` ?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "composed". Any subset of $X$ will be contained in (but perhaps not equal to) a union of these equivalence classes. If $A$ is saturated, then by *definition* it must be equal to a union of equivalences classes.

Comment: The condition in $(\star)$ is an equivalent definition of saturation, for instance.