# Name for a partition that "restricts nicely" to a set

Tags: reference-request, definition

Let $A$ be a finite set and let $P$ be a partition of $A$ into subsets.  Let $B\subset A$ be some subset of $A$.  I want an adjective that describes partitions $P$ such that, for every $S\in P$, either $S\subset B$ or $S\cap B=\emptyset$.  In other words, I want an adjective for the partitions that refine the partition $\{B,A\setminus B\}$.

I am tempted to write for example that $P$ is "$B$-local", since it does not pair any elements of $B$ with any elements outside of $B$.  But I wonder if this gives the wrong impression.

I would appreciate any reference to any book or paper that uses this concept and gives it a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology is that $B$ is a [saturated subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173523/definition-of-saturated-set) of $A$ (with respect to the partition $P$). You can find references to this in topological contexts, where it is used commonly in discussions of the [quotient topology and quotient maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map). It is used in the general context of a partition of any set, not just finite sets.